# Update listview's viewitems without notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview

I have an android application with a listview which .. blablabla ..  presents a title and adress of a location. Furthermore it displays a distance in meters and a compas.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5XHF.jpg (Sorry cant post screenshots yet :)

Whenever i get new compas data from my SensorManagers listener, i do notifyDataSetChanged the list is updated with the new bearing and everythings fine, however it seems to freeze the application for a few ms, nothing serious but the user can sure feel this laggy effect.

And now to my real question:

**Is it possible to update only the "compasviews" without doing notifyDataSetChanged?**
I thought the best way to go about this would be some "findviewsbyid"function, save the destination in the compasview it self and only update the compasview, but i can only find the findViewById method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing extensive calculations on the UI-thread? If so, consider implementing an `AsyncTask` for calculating the new values and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onPostExecute()`-method of your `AsyncTask`.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
        //Do calculations here
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        //Submit new data to the listadapter
        adapater.notifyDataSetChanged();
    };
}
```

Comment: Not really, however i'm calculating distances and bearing to the location in the Adapter.getView, but if that where the problem, shouldn't the list lag whenever it was dragged?

Comment: If you do calculations in `getView()` you'll probably experience lag when a new View enters the list (you scroll down/up and the next/previous ListItem)

Comment: Okay now i'm doing all calculations in a AsyncTask and `getView` only reads the precalculated values. Its given the list some performance boost, its still not perfect but i dont really know how i can find the problem. (But i dont think its the `notifyDataSetChanged`) And by the way its performance is really acceptable so ill just leave it there.